# Sourcing external R scripts in Shiny App in R 4.0 vs 3.6.1

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that was working perfectly until the update to R 4.0. The app calls a couple of external helper R scripts, which are being sourced so the functions within will be available globally. The scripts are sourced outside of both the UI and Server components, so should be available in the global environment, I believe.

```
Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
cannot open file 'RAW_DATA_ADAPT5_vAdDS.R': No such file or directory
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
cannot open the connection
```

The error is unusual, because it's what I'd expect to get when the file isn't in the directory being specified. However, as I said, the script was working well as of R 3.6.1. Anyone have any insights as to what may have changed?

I did try to move the script sourcing into a globals.R file, but that didn't help.

edit:

The shiny version has also been updated since (1.5, now). The App is set up such that:

```
LaunchApp.R
MyBatchFileToRunLaunchApp.bat
App/app.R
App/R/<external R Scripts>.R
```

The source is being called as `if(file.exists("R/<external R Script>.R)){source("R/<external R Script>.R")}`

However, I also tested different versions where I moved the scripts into the same directory as app.R (with changing the source command) and then another test where I moved the block of code within app.R that does the sourcing into a global.R script in the same directory as app.R.

Comment: Did you also change shiny versions? How exactly is your app set up? What is your working directory when you run the app? How are you running the app?

Comment: I edited the main post with most of the info, however the main answer to your question is that the App is being launched by a batch call to a separate R script outside the app directory. The app itself is next to a 'R' directory that houses the external scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved through some combing of the Shiny documentation. Apparently, R will automatically call all *.R files in a 'R' directory that is with the app of interest. In my case, some of these files weren't supposed to be called by the app (they were there for validation purposes to be used outside the app, but called some of the same R scripts in that folder.

Solution was to remove all the excess .R files that weren't supposed be called by the app from the R directory.

Answer (score 0):

The change was made in Shiny v1.4.0 (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/NEWS.md#shiny-140)

You can revert to the older behaviour by setting the following option `options(shiny.autoload.r=FALSE)`, either in your script or in something like your `.Rprofile` file